# Sort by Ascending Order in vba with Variable Last Row

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a hard time analyzing the problem in my code. I need to sort ColumnE by ascending order but the problem is the rows that should not be included in the sorting was also sorted.

[image]

The highlighted in yellow should not be included in the sorting process. I need to start the sorting in row3.

Here is my code:

```
        'sort by ascending order
        wsRD.Columns("C:E").Sort key1:=wsRD.Range("E1"), _
        order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in  my code? Appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: If the highlighted cells are on the bottom of your data, instead `wsRD.Columns("C:E")` try `wsRD.Columns("C3:E" & LastRow)` being `LastRow = wsRD.Range("C3").End(xlDown).Row - 1`

Comment: @Damian - why `-1` for the last row?

Comment: @Vityata because if the highlighted is on the last row, you don't want it to get on the sort range, so you get the -1 to leave it out the range.

Comment: @Damian - I see what you mean. However, I guess that the issue is that the highlighted is originally on the 2. row, see the left screenshot. And it appears to be on the last one, which is the problem.

Comment: Then you don't need the -1 you are right @Vityata but the code is the same.

Comment: @Damian - I am not sure that `Columns()` would accept range string as a parameter.

Comment: Absolutely right @Vityata it's `wsRD.Range("C3:E" & LastRow)` being `LastRow = wsRD.Range("C3").End(xlDown).Row`

Comment: Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header in the example consists of two rows. And the `Header:=xlYes` expects only the first row to be a header, thus the second line is taken as part of the values to be sorted.

To fix it, use `Range("C1:E" & lastRow5).Sort key1:=Range("E2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes`, which takes the lastRow of the fifth column of the `ActiveSheet` with `lastRow(ActiveSheet.Name, 5)`.

The whole solution:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim lastRow5 As Long
    lastRow5 = lastRow(ActiveSheet.Name, 5)
    Range("C1:E" & lastRow5).Sort key1:=Range("E2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

End Sub

Function lastRow(wsName As String, Optional columnToCheck As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(wsName)
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, columnToCheck).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Your selection contains 2 header rows. You can either merge these headers, or set the range in your code as below (change the 9999 as needed):

```
    'sort by ascending order
    wsRD.Range("C2:E9999").Sort key1:=wsRD.Range("E2"), _
    order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```